# Where's my pet gone to?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, word-search

I came home today and realized that my furry friend was not there to greet me. There was a note on the counter from my SO that explained where they had gone but I wasn't quite sure what it meant. Can you help tell me where they went and why?

 Hints:

> You do not need to solve the sudoku. There is a hint to what the note's numbers mean that you can get from just looking at it. 
>  N E S W 
>  *[Time](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/map/)* is of the essence.

I was left this:

[image]
A small note:

> The +2 (mixed +3) -11 s

And this for some reason:

[image]

Comment: Please be a gerbil.... :P

Comment: I'll be honest.. I didn't check if it could be solved nor do I care if it can be solved...

Comment: I deleted my answer because I just checked my answer, but there are 155 solutions. I see something is going on at a deeper level...

Comment: Neat.. that's quite a few solutions.. xD.. and @YowE3K while that's creative, I'll let you know that won't help.. that's like the 3rd puzzle of mine that someone's suggested that is a possibility

Comment: Perhaps the Sudoku grid is to be layered over the searchaword type grid?

Comment: Your pet has clearly gone insane after it evolved to have enough intelligence to create puzzles and it has gone to a clinic (the one word I can find in the crossword) to get help

Comment: Are you expecting the truth, or the answer your parents told you? Because "the farm" and "the crematorium" are different.

Comment: Ouch that's dark... But location has already been determined.. just the note left

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a community wiki answer which serves as a collection of responses from [Techidiot](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/50312/34679), [Maria](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/50313/34679), and [Wesley](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/50546/34679).

Maria solved most of the word search, determining that:

> The pet is at the vet. See her answer for a story using the words found within the word search.

Techidiot solved the sudoku one of the 100 some ways that it can be solved, however it was not the intent. In chat he made his way into figuring out:

> The sudoku has the numbers 12, 3, 6, 9 in the N E S W positions, resembling a clock. (With a little help from Wesley here too)

Wesley finished up the puzzle, figuring out the meaning behind the note:

> His answer includes a clock explaination, and that the numbers were interpreted as time zones. The abbreviations lead to CAT, EAT and NUT.

Then

> He then noted that you were supposed to mix EAT to get ATE. This left you with the final note of **The CAT ATE NUTs**.

Finally

> Nuts are in fact toxic to most cats and dogs when ingested, making it reasonable that they visited the vet.

Answer (score 5):

**Partial**

**The Sudoku**

> [image]
>
>  Also, I have the text version(numbers converted to letters), if it may help
>
> ```
>  C E F A B D H I G 
>  A H B I C G D E F
>  D G I F H E C B A
>  B C E H A F I G D
>  I A D G E B F H C
>  G F H C D I E A B
>  E D C B G H A F I
>  F B A E I C G D H
>  H I G D F A B C E
> ```

**The Word Search**

> Well, it looks like it's not a circle but a circle with a cross over it. Which is, suspicious....
>
>  [image]

**The Note**

> No idea so far how to read it or where to use it...

Comment: Here is where I got with the word search: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tGYl.png Words I am sure were included: Clinical
Animal's Doctor
Emergency
Examination
Medicine
Thermometer
White
Blood
Needles
Assistance
Bug   Words I am not really sure:Boom
Boa
Tump
Goat
Bass

Comment: @MariaDeleva You can go ahead and post your findings. I didn't do any word search :-)

Comment: You probably didn't see it but Gerbil already tried solving the sudoku and as was pointed out there are like 155+ solutions to it... the tag isn't there for a reason... the cross over the circle was just for taste ;)

Comment: @n_palum Oh, didn't knew. Well, clearly it has went to a *vet* :-)

Comment: I figured you were not around when he did that.. and good, you're half way :) I would *cough* *cough* recommend undoing the first part

Answer (score 5):

**Partial answer**

**The word-search grid:**

> [image]
>
>
>  Words I have found (in blue and green): 
>  **Clinical, Animal's Doctor, Emergency, Examination, Medicine, Thermometer, White, Blood, Needles, Assistance**

So, the pet:

> Went to the animal's doctor in the (veterinary) clinic because it had an emergency and needed an examination and assistance. Perhaps, the doctor was dressed in white, and used needles to take blood from the pet for medical tests and used the thermometer as well.
>  And, of course, at the end, the doctor prescribed the medicine to heal your pet.

Comment: @Techidiot Thanks. Courtesy of MS Paint. :-D

Comment: Do you mean 'could have been unintended' instead of 'could not have been intended' (as there is a possibility they were intended, though slim)? Also, if you are doing that, I can find 'do', 'if', 'on', 'in', 'be', 'job', etc.

Comment: Well, bass, goat and boa are animals. Boom - could refer to an accident or something. Tump is probably unintended. I have not considered any words less than 3 letters, and I also found pug, top and some others as well, but did not include them.

Comment: Everything except bug was intended that you have right now, and you are right about the unintended ones. Finding all the answers isn't all that important - just meant to give you the location.

Comment: @MariaDeleva I appreciate the little story you've gathered together :) I'm sure you can reveal the note too

Comment: @n_palum I really have no clue for the note. I am thinking perhaps some chemical compound, or a recipe for something. Or perhaps the numbers from the grid should also be used somehow... But nothing really strikes me.

Comment: Since you didn't attempt the sudoku as others have, and didn't have to be told it's not needed to solve.. maybe that'll help.. you're right that numbers are important

Answer (score 5):

For the reason as to why

> the pet is at the vet:
>
>  We take a look at the Sudoku and the note.
>
>  The circular shape of the word-search and the numbers 12, 3, 6, and 9 on the north, east, south, and west borders of the Sudoku hint towards something with time.
>
>  We can interpret the +2, +3, and -11 as time zones, which each have an abbreviation associated with them.
>
>  GMT+2 = CAT
>  GMT+3 = EAT
>  GMT-11 = NUT
>
>  The note says to mix EAT, so we take an anagram of that to be ATE.
>
>  The message then says: **The CAT ATE NUTs**
>
>  Nuts are toxic for cats when ingested, so this would be a reasonable reason for the visit to the vet.

Comment: Yup that would be it :) I tried so hard to get Techidiot there